# Mysql Lock Tables 100% guarantee that only one user can edit?

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES `counter` WRITE;") or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `unID` FROM `counter`;") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$unID = $row['unID'] + 1;
mysql_query("UPDATE `counter` SET `unID`=`unID`+1;") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is 100% guarantee that *$unID* will be unique for every user who visit web ?

mysql table type: MyISAM

Comment: If you're locking MySQL just to generate a unique user token, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 100% guarantee... and what happens if the same user comes in from 2 different IP addresses etc... this gets number of views, not even number of unique views

Comment: @Mahmoud AL-Qudsi i don't want to use InnoDB, so the only way to get unique ID in MyISAM is using LOCK TABLES, right ?

Comment: @Ben I don't use this for count total amount of users and they IP's im using this counter for other reasons. So I need only to know, will this unID be unique for every user who visits my site, even when 10 users are connecting in the same time.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, what are you talking about? The locking calls are blocking. Simultaneous hits don't trigger errors. That would render table locking useless. While the code and usefulness of the question may not be top-quality, it is still a valid question.

Comment: @Matthew I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released.

So the answer is yes, the number will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just create a sequence table:

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequence VALUES (0);
```

Then use this query to get the next id:

```
UPDATE sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
```

You can fetch the id by using `mysql_insert_id()`.

Btw, try to use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: @waza123 no problem, it actually performs better than your own and is also 100% unique :)